# OpenMesh with topology only, no data

Tags: c++, geometry, openmesh

Is it possible to use OpenMesh to construct a DCEL with no data? In my particular use case the vertex data is owned by a 3rd party closed source application and I would like to use OpenMesh to traverse that data. The documentation discusses redefining the `Point` type and also adding new data but not removing the `Point` data.